# How to save selected rows from UITableview to NSString variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode3.2

I am new to xcode and making my first iPhone app.

I have a `UITableview` with 8 rows in a tabbed screen. I have a code which let's the user select maximum 4 rows at a time and mark it with checks when selected.

Now, when I change the view and navigate to the next tab I want to save the text from these checked rows in a single `NSString` variable separated by commas.

Is it possible to do so? Thank you, any help is very much appreciated.

Here is the code of the first tab from where I want to save the selected rows.

```
@implementation Psychological

static int count = 0;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[listOfItems addObject:@"1 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"2 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"3 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"4 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"5 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"6 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"7 option"];
[listOfItems addObject:@"8 option"];    

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [listOfItems count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


// Configure the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.text = cellValue;



return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    if(count < 4)
    {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        count++;
    }

} else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    count --;
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}


- (void)dealloc {

[listOfItems release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way is make method wich will return string that you need. Method will look something like this:

```
- (NSString *) selectedItems {
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i = 0; i < [itemsArray count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
            [result appendFormat:@"%@",cell.textLabel.text];
        }
    }
    if (result.length > 2) {
        [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(result.length-1, 1) withString:@""];
    }
return result;
}
```

To get this line in another view controller you should find Psychological view controller in navigationController.viewController and call this method.

```
- (void) method {
    for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[Psychological class]]) {
            NSString *str = vc.selectedItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi this is precisely what I am looking for. I just did not get where to call this method?
Should this be called in the next tab? If so where exactly? Sorry for the stupid question, I am really new to xcode!!!

Comment: Yes in the next tab. I think you need to call this in viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: Thank you, in the above code it gives an error saying tableView undeclared?

Comment: Past the name of your table instead tableView

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code suits your requirement:

//didSelect method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

     if(count < 4) {

         [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
         [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
         count++;
     }

  } else {

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    count --;
}

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Declare the selectedCell globally to access in all tabs

```
NSMutableString *selectedCell = [[NSMutableString alloc]init]; //Should declare this string globally
```

//Use the following code in -viewWillDisappear Method or where you feel it fits (method that called when navigating from present class)

```
for(int i = 0; i < [selectedIndexes count]; i++){

 [selectedCell appendString:[selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:i];
 [selectedCell appendString:@","];

}

NSRange range = {[selectedCell length]-1,1};
[selectedCell deleteCharactersInRange:range];
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, but won't this add all the selected rows to the string (which will include rows which were checked and uncheked again)?

Comment: Dont use this part of code in didSelect delegate method, instead use it where all the selection is finalized. SelectedIndexes array would hold the finalized selection (returned from -didSelect method). But if you still want to use it in didSelect method,.. try the new edited Code

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *selectedRow=[NSMutableString alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<[count];i++)
{
    selectedRow=[arrayName objectAtIndex:row];
    [selectedRow appendString:@","];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
if(count<4){
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Selected"];
count++;
}

    } else if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        if(count>=0){
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"Selected"];
count--;
    }  
}
```

replace  above code and when you want to navigate your page at that time check whether Selected value yes or no if yes then pass that value otherwise leave it.

```
for (int i =0 ; i<[listOfItems count]; i++) {
        if ([[[listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Selected"]isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            if ([selectedId length]==0) {
                selectedId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user_id"]];
            }else {
                selectedId = [selectedId stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",[[listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user_id"]];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a global array. 
Store the selected values into that global array then it would be easy to display them elsewhere.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class, let's call it `Option`, and give it two properties.  One is a NSString called `name` and the other is a BOOL called `selected`.  Instead of having `listOfItems` as an array of strings, make it a list of `Option` objects.  Have each `Option` keep track of whether or not it's currently selected.

Make the controller class that owns `listOfItems` into a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` so that it builds the string and passes it to the next selected controller.